# FTP to use SSL/TLS

Tags: linux, security, ssl, ftp, linux-networking

I have two applications

a) App-1 - Which is a FTP client (ftp client functionality is built-in into the application code). This is deployed of Host-1.

b) App-2 - Which is a FTP server (ftp server functionality is built-in into the application code). This is deployed on Host-2

Both of these applications are COTS product and are sitting in the internal network and communicating with each other. In addition, both of these application have other Business Logic and performs lot of analysis and computation. Since both these application use their own code and not use OS provided FTP client and server (package) I am stuck.

We recently had an security audit and have been asked NOT to use FTP. The problem is we do not have access to the application code and we want these application to use SSL/TLS (secure channels for communication). I was wondering if there are any solutions which we can use to fix this issue.

Some of the solution that comes to my mind are:
1. Using stunnel based SSL/TLS tunnel on both Host-1 and Host-2 but here the signaling and data channels become the issue. 
2. Host-1 to Host-2 IPSEC tunnel.

Can anyone help me with how to setup either of these to make it functional? I am also open to other solutions (except changing the applications or its code).

Thanks
Garry

Comment: Is a ssh tunneling an acceptable Solution? (some security policy does not permit this)

Comment: I agree with you on this one @AlessandroCarini

Comment: VPN between them?

Answer (score 0):

Restricting SSL/TLS to only selected ports like done with stunnel or SSH forwarding is not possible because the design of FTP uses dynamic ports for the data transfer. This leaves some local proxy on each site which could translate between FTP and FTPS and back (don't know if there is a product for this) or a VPN/IPSec between the two systems.

Comment: On internal network (no NAT involved) FTP does not need to be in PASV

Comment: @AlessandroCarini: I have no idea what this comment relates to. Could you explain it in more detail? If it refers to passive vs. active mode then I can not see any relation to this answer since dynamic ports for data connections are used in both cases - the only difference is which side allocates the listener and announces the port.

Comment: I agree with @SteffenUllrich The only solution that I am able to think of is having a point-to-point IPSEC channel created between the two host to make sure all traffic between these go over secure and encrypted channel. However, this will affect the SLAs because of compression/ decompression and encryption/decryption overhead.